# How to make generic protocol with associatedtype not generic via protocol inheritance?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types, generic-associated-types

I have generic protocol with associated type and at some point would like to make it not generic. The same behaviour works fine with classes but unfortunately I can't use the same logic with protocols. For instance this is absolutely fine:

```
class Validator<Value> {
    func validate(_ value: Value?) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

class StingValidator: Validator<String> {
}

class EmptyStringValidator: StingValidator {
    override func validate(_ value: String?) -> String? {
        return ((value?.isEmpty ?? true) == true) ? "Empty" : nil
    }
}

func anyfunc() {
    let validator: StingValidator = EmptyStringValidator()
}
```

But using protocols I am getting compile error

> Protocol 'StringValidatorProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

```
protocol ValidatorProtocol {
    associatedtype Value
    func validate(_ value: Value?) -> String?
}

protocol StringValidatorProtocol: ValidatorProtocol where Value == String {
}

struct EmptyStringValidator: StringValidatorProtocol {
    func validate(_ value: String?) -> String? {
        return ((value?.isEmpty ?? true) == true) ? "Empty" : nil
    }
}

func anyfunc() {
    let validator: StringValidatorProtocol = EmptyStringValidator()
}
```

Any ideas? Is there any way to make generic protocol not generic? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve in the end? In your example you can just say `let validator = EmptyStringValidator()` and it will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I I mentioned in the title I would like to make generic protocol with associatedtype not generic. And I would like to operate with it like with protocol, not the class or struct. 
Therefore I would like my validator (as a variable) be a not generic protocol type inherited somehow from ValidatorProtocol and use it as a protocol not as a struct.

Comment: Ok, clear :). It sounds like you need type erasure for this, but it's hard to say without an actual code example. Can you maybe include some code for what you want to do? That way we can look at the point where it actually breaks, instead of a contrived example.

Comment: That `== true` is redundant, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Making a protocol with associated type not generic is simply not possible and I think what you needed is more generics:

```
func anyfunc() {
    let validator: StringValidatorProtocol = EmptyStringValidator()
}
```

with a free function you can't do what you're trying to do, but inside a class or a struct:

```
protocol ValidatorProtocol {
    associatedtype Value
    init()
    func validate(_ value: Value?) -> String?
}

protocol StringValidatorProtocol: ValidatorProtocol where Value == String {
}

class EmptyStringValidator: StringValidatorProtocol {
    required init() {
        
    }
    func validate(_ value: String?) -> String? {
        return value?.isEmpty ?? true ? "Empty" : nil
    }
}

class MyClass<Validator: ValidatorProtocol> {
    static func validate(_ string: Validator.Value?) -> String? {
        let validator: Validator = Validator()
        return validator.validate(string)
    }
}
MyClass<EmptyStringValidator>.validate("Hello World") // nil
MyClass<EmptyStringValidator>.validate("") // "Empty"
MyClass<EmptyStringValidator>.validate(nil) // "Empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "make it not generic" means, but let us know via an edit if this is not enough for you:

The error you've shown can be solved with an opaque constant.

```swift
let validator: some StringValidatorProtocol = EmptyStringValidator()
```